# Using fetch from JavaScript to get one meal recipe form an API "TheMealDB" I can´t access=>error 404

Tags: javascript, rest, cors, fetch-api

```
/* Create an event loader to all of the events */
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>{
    let button = document.querySelector("#button");
    let firstCont = document.querySelector(".container2");
    let secondCont = document.querySelector(".container3");
    
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      dataRenovation(firstCont, secondCont);
      firstCont.classList.remove("hidden");
      secondCont.classList.remove("hidden");
    })
  });
  
  function dataRenovation(first, second){
    const option = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://www.themealdb.com/"  
      }
    };
    
    fetch("www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php", option)
    .then(response => {
        alert(response.url);
      if(response.ok) {
        return response.json;
      }else {
        throw new Error(response.status);
      }
    })
    .then(data => {
      alert("Data: " + data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      alert("Error: " + err.message);
    });
  }
```

It returns error: 404. I have noticed that the URL returned is not the original, Js return the normal URL preceded by my actual domain direction at this case http://127.0.0.1:5500/ as the normal domain.

I read something about cors and added `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://www.themealdb.com/"` to can access to the normal API but I don´t know if that´s the correct implementation.

I´d like to get some help and if you can let me some links to learn more about API and Cors.

Comment: You need `//` at the beginning of the URL. Otherwise it's a filename relative to the current URL.

Comment: Interesting, it has worked; return me the normal message:  Access to fetch at 'http://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request. So I have added at the option the mode: 'no-cors', It solved this last error. Now what happens is that return me at the error alert Error: 0.

Comment: The API doesn't allow cross-origin use. You need to make the call from the server, not the client.

Comment: So this is where the backed knowlage comnes in?